# DNS record contains 0.0.0.0 address

Tags: domain-name-system

Long story short.

`dig c.cx`

returns

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.0-P2 <<>> c.cx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32806
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;c.cx.              IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
c.cx.           6903    IN  A   0.0.0.0

;; Query time: 90 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 06 22:33:08 +03 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49
```

i. e. address `0.0.0.0`.

Questions:

- does it have any special meaning?
- is it legal (are there any limitations on what addresses dns record can contain)?

Comment: I thought it was an attempt at "controlled interruption" similar to 127.0.53.53 (see https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2-2014-08-01-en) but given it has MXs zero.c.cx and null.c.cx that resolve to 0.0.0.0 as well I think it is somebody messing around. For an example of controlled interruption run `host a.prod`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is legal (see [RFC1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) §3.4.1), but useless (as it would mean "any IP"). As for the meaning, please have a look at [Zoneedit FAQ](http://sunset.zoneedit.com/faq.html)  (which is wrong BTW, there is no mandatory requirement to have an A record on the domain name itself, quite the contrary, all MTAs can use MX records) :

> 32. Why can't I delete the "A" record for the root name of my domain?
>
> All domains must have an "A" record for the root of the domain. Omitting this "A" record may prevent some mail servers from delivering your email correctly. WebParking or WebForwarding the root of your domain is sufficient, because both of these create hidden "A" records pointing to our servers. If you're really looking to delete this record, try changing the IP address to "0.0.0.0" instead, it's functionally equivalent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140772/discussion-on-answer-by-patrick-mevzek-dns-record-contains-0-0-0-0-address).

Answer (score 4):

Famously it was used to shut down parler.com by the domain registrar epik

```
$ dig @NS3.EPIK.COM parler.com

; <<>> DiG blah blah blah <<>> @NS3.EPIK.COM parler.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43362
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;parler.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
parler.com.     300 IN  A   0.0.0.0
```

The result was to serve an error page from the local web server.

Answer (score 3):

*There's a lot of misinformation circulating at the moment about 0.0.0.0 so be very careful to read definitions carefully, look for authoritative sources, and make your own conclusions.*

### Official Meaning / Official Use

IANA, who have authority over IP addresses, [have reserved 0.0.0.0/32](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml) for it's definition in [RFC 1122 Section 3.2.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3).  RFC 1122 is concerned with low level protocols only (IP itself).   RFC describes it as meaning "this host on this network" and prohibit's it's use as a destination address *(on the wire)*:

> ```
> (a)  { 0, 0 }
>
>         This host on this network.  MUST NOT be sent, except as
>         a source address as part of an initialization procedure
>         by which the host learns its own IP address.>
>
>         See also Section 3.3.6 for a non-standard use of {0,0}.
> ```

This is also mentioned in RFC 5735.

So in theory it should never be used for anything else!

### Unofficial use - Internal OS (Linux)

If a program on Linux tries to connect to 0.0.0.0 it will connect to itself (localhost).  I'm not sure if other OS do this.

Strictly speaking, as a reserved IP address by IANA, this may not be standards compliant.  However this behaviour is very old and may even date back to early [Berkly Sockets released in 1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) *(I'm not sure)*.  It also seems relatively close to RFC 1122 definition naming it `This host on this network`.

To be precise:

- Attempting to [`bind`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) to 0.0.0.0 results in allowing incoming messages to any of the host's IP addresses.
- Attempting to [`connect`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) to 0.0.0.0 results in connecting to localhost.

### Unofficial use - DNS

More recently some DNS servers and server software has begun to use 0.0.0.0 as a [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_(networking)) address.  This use is getting much more common but has problems including:

- It directly conflicts with the *reserved* IANA / RFC definition.  It does not even seem to honour the original meaning in name let alone function.
- There seems to be no standardised definition of what a host should do when told to connect to 0.0.0.0.  This therefore relies on [unspecified behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior).
- **It does NOT always result in a black hole**.  On some devices it results in a localhost connection.  The result of actually connecting to something might well be undesirable.

### It it legal? - That's complicated

DNS does not explicitly prohibit it; not in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) or [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) anyway.  This means that DNS servers and clients are unlikely to reject it out right.

But be warned. It is not the job of DNS standards to define what is and is not a valid resource IP address.  That is generally outside the scope of DNS RFCs.  DNS only defines how to convey name <--> IP mappings.  Just because DNS is able to convey illegal name --> IP mapping does not make it legal.

Since 0.0.0.0 is an illegal destination address under IP, it's hard to see how it could ever be a "legal" resource IP address stored on a network's DNS server.

I believe ultimate responsibility for defining what is an isn't a valid resource IP would sit somewhere between IANA and other networking RFCs.

### *Conclusion*

*I personally believe it is a **bad idea** to configure any DNS to point to 0.0.0.0.  I've seen undesirable behaviour as a result and it is very hard to mitigate without changing the DNS resource record.*

*Personally I would use one of the IANA / RFC allocated "localhost" ip range that is extremely uncommon (eg 127.253.252.251).  At least this is defined as localhost should it actually connect to localhost, unlike 0.0.0.0.  But then that's just me.*

Answer (score 0):

It means it is a blackhole : you can't join it as it is your network (or loopback on my system).
The IP is valid, so the A entry is valid.

I think it is an error from the dns master, but maybe it is wanted...

Comment: Assigning the IPv4 address 0.0.0.0 to an A record (and the IPv6 address :: to an AAAA record) is apparently used by NextDNS in place of the correct IP addresses to block domains, so this could be intentional.

Answer (score -1):

The IP address "0.0.0.0" is a black hole address which causes the lookup to go to nothing. This can be us full in split DNS scenarios where internal network and external network share the same domain name. You may have a wildcard DNS entry that point to your website (seems sensible) but then a laptop from your org trys to connect to "fileserver.contoso.com" and caches the main website IP as the wildcard returned it.

added fileserver.contoso.com to your external DNS pointing to 0.0.0.0 will stop the address being cached. there for when you reconnect to the VPN (and get back on the internal network) fileserver.contoso.com will still work.

if you did not have the external address pointing to 0.0.0.0 you would not be able to access the fileserver until the TTL expired.

I know limited use case but I have seen this used!